# Wget on Linux without svn?

Tags: linux, svn, unix

I am trying to get a svn repository using wget.  I have:

```
wget -m -np http://svn.wikia-code.com/wikia/releases/release-126/
```

This does not work and starts to pull down everything above too.  I just want the release 126 folder and everything it contains.

What is the correct syntax please?

SOLUTION found by me:

wget -r -np http://svn.wikia-code.com/wikia/releases/release-126/

Comment: Why can't you use the `svn` command directly, e.g. `svn co -r126 http://svn.wikia-code.com/wikia` etc....?

Comment: I can't use svn because it changes the king on the folder and files to root and then the wikia does not install correctly.

Comment: Ask on the project's site how you should install and use their software.

Comment: *it changes the king on the folder and files* **Changes the *what*** ?

Comment: @cnicutar it changes the king.  That is like who can make changes to the files and folder.  You can find more information on wikipedia about it.

Comment: @David19801 Can you link me to a page describing this *king* ?

Comment: @David19801: you are certainly using the wrong word. `king` has not such technical meaning (perhaps you mean "parent directory"?). Please check in a dictionary the English words you are using.

Comment: @cnicutar yes.  I searched for wikipedia file owner on Google and found this for you.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions. If you scroll down to permission I think that is it.  If a king owns it then you cannot write to the file until you call him to fix it.

Comment: @David19801 I can't find the word "king" on that page ?

Comment: @cnicutar That is just how our guy explained it.  We are like the farmers and root is the king.  So if we are stuck call him.  But he is away for the weekend.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, please *CREATE AN ANSWER* and *MARK THIS QUESTION ANSWERED*

Comment: Maybe you need a revolution in which to overthrow your king ?

Comment: @David19801 No it isn't answered. Create an answer and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I still cannot decide if I should upvote this question for sheer hilarity...

Answer (score 0):

You are getting higher-level directories because the `-m` switch for `wget` follows all links. The first link on the directory listing points to the parent directory.

As others have correctly pointed out, you should be checking out the code with `svn co`, or following the project's instructions for acquiring & installing the software.